# Knockout data-bind if else condition

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

In my current project, I have a knockout binding where the layout height should be applied according to the value received as true or false. Following is my binding code

```
data-bind="style: {height: showOld ? '392px' : '275px'}"
```

The `showOld` gives either `true` or `false` correctly, but, regardless what it returns, it always take `392px`. If the `showOld` gives `true` then `392px` should return else `275px` should return. Any help to fix this issue is highly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `showOld` is `ko.observable` then you need to write `showOld()` (because `ko.observable` is a function) to get its value in your expression:

```
data-bind="style: {height: showOld() ? '392px' : '275px'}"
```

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading_and_writing_observables):

> To **read** the observable’s current value, just call the observable with
>   no parameters.
>
> To **write** a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass the new value as a parameter. For example, calling `myViewModel.personName('Mary')` will change the name value to 'Mary'.

Comment: Don't worry...no matter how often you use Knockout you'll always find yourself omitting the '()' from time to time. Key is to know to look for it when nothing else seems possible. Using the ko.debug.js reference is useful also...where the binding error is thrown, you can watch the 'node' parameter and see exactly what/where the grief is coming from in the case of an inline ko binding.